# Powershell output in one line

Tags: powershell, one-liner

I'm pretty new when it comes to scripting with powershell (or in general whe it comes to scripting). The problem that i have, is that i got a bunch of variables i want to output in one line. Here is not the original but simplified code:

```
$a = 1
$b = 2
$c = $a; $b;
Write-output $c
```

The output looks like this:

```
1
2
```

You may guess how i want the output to look like:

```
12
```

I've searched the net to get a solution but nothing seem to work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `"$a$b"`, the semi colon in Powershell means *statement termination*. So, since `$c` is a reference to `$a`, it prints out *1* due to the semicolon sperating the two variables of `$a` and `$b`. So, you're basically saying, *print `$a`, then print `$b`*.

Answer (score 6):

Right now you're only assigning `$a` to `$c` and then outputting `$b` separately - use the `@()` array subexpression operator to create `$c` instead:

```
$c = @($a; $b)
```

Then, use the `-join` operator to concatenate the two values into a single string:

```
$c -join ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make things easier on yourself using member access or `Select-Object` to retrieve property values. Once the values are retrieved, you can them manipulate them.

It is not completely clear what you really need, but the following is a blueprint of how to get the desired system data from your code.

```
# Get Serial Number
$serial = Get-CimInstance CIM_BIOSElement | Select-Object -Expand SerialNumber

# Serial Without Last Digit
$serialMinusLast = $serial -replace '.$'

# First 7 characters of Serial Number
# Only works when serial is 7 or more characters
$serial.Substring(0,7)
# Always works
$serial -replace '(?<=^.{7}).*$'

# Get Model
$model = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -Expand Model

# Get First Character and Last 4 Characters of Model
$modelSubString = $model -replace '^(.).*(.{4})$','$1$2'

# Output <model substring - serial number substring>
"{0}-{1}" -f $modelSubString,$serialMinusLast

# Output <model - serial number>
"{0}-{1}" -f $model,$serial
```

---

Using the syntax `$object | Select-Object -Expand Property` will retrieve the value of `Property` only due to the use of `-Expand` or `-ExpandProperty`. You could opt to use member access, which uses the syntax `$object.Property`, to achieve the same result.

If you have an array of elements, you can use the `-join` operator to create a single string of those array elements.

```
$array = 1,2,3,'go'
# single string
$array -join ''
```

The string format operator `-f` can be used to join components into a single string. It allows you to easily add extra characters between the substrings.